# How do i repeat my function multiple times with updated values?

Tags: python

How do i repeat this function over and over again, but using v_2 as the updated vi e.g. if i got v_2 = 3 then i want to repeat this code where the new vi would be 3 and it calculates a new v_2 and it repeats this until it reaches a certain time, t_max.

I need the results to be in a list form.

```
import math

def trackflow(f_in, f_out, r, H, h, t_max, t_open):


    t = 0.1
    vi = 0
    hi = 0
    ti = 0


    if ti == t_open:
        v_2 = vi + (f_in - f_out)*t
        h_2 = hi + ((f_in - f_out)*t)/(math.pi*r**2)

        print(v_2)
        print(h_2)
        print(ti + 0.1)


    else:
        f_out = 0 
        v_2 = vi + (f_in - f_out)*t
        h_2 = hi + ((f_in - f_out)*t)/(math.pi*r**2)

        print(v_2)
        print(h_2)
        print(ti + 0.1)
```

Comment: return values from the function then recall it instead of printing

Comment: you need Recursive Functions https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your if else statement in a for loop, it will keep the updated variables, and put t_max in the brackets.

Example code:

```
for x in range(t_max):
    if ti == t_open:
        v_2 = vi + (f_in - f_out)*t
        h_2 = hi + ((f_in - f_out)*t)/(math.pi*r**2)

        print(v_2)
        print(h_2)
        print(ti + 0.1)


    else:
        f_out = 0 
        v_2 = vi + (f_in - f_out)*t
        h_2 = hi + ((f_in - f_out)*t)/(math.pi*r**2)

        print(v_2)
        print(h_2)
        print(ti + 0.1)
trackflow((Fill in here the values for the define to work))
```

Edit:
To go with what i saw in the comments, you would use a while loop instead of the for loop. I'm not 100 percent sure where the equal to bit would be but im putting it where I think it would be as its all depends on if its in the while or out, and when its equal to, place in the False statement.

Comment: why does it come up with an error t_max is not defined when t_max is defined in the def trackflow(f_in, f_out, r, H, h, t_max, t_open)?

Comment: t_max is not predefined, t_max in the define does not have a number. If you understand global variables, then putting it into the define is like declaring it a global variable, you still need the initial number.

Comment: range(t_max) means it will stop after t_max value, how do i get it to stop when ti = t_max ?

Comment: So when ti equals to t_max, you want it to stop?

Comment: i want it to stop when ti = t_max or if hi > H or hi < 0

Comment: I updated the answer, you place the false where you wish it to stop, just change the for into a while.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You could use a loop inside the function to repeat it a given amount of times:

```
import math
def trackflow(f_in, f_out, r, H, h, t_max, t_open, n_repeats):
    t = 0.1
    vi = 0
    hi = 0
    ti = 0

    for i in range(n_repeats):
        if ti == t_open:
            v_2 = vi + (f_in - f_out)*t
            h_2 = hi + ((f_in - f_out)*t)/(math.pi*r**2)

            print(v_2)
            print(h_2)
            print(ti + 0.1)


        else:
            f_out = 0 
            v_2 = vi + (f_in - f_out)*t
            h_2 = hi + ((f_in - f_out)*t)/(math.pi*r**2)

            print(v_2)
            print(h_2)
            print(ti + 0.1)
        vi = v_2
```

or you can also take vi as an input to the function and set v_2 as an output with `return(v_2)` at the end of the function and build a loop that repeats the function:

```
vi = 0
for i in range(100):
    vnew = trackflow(f_in, f_out, r, H, h, t_max, t_open, vi)
    vi = vnew
```